# how to check if a colmmande return is true or false selenium-ide

Tags: web, selenium-ide

I'm trying to get a command return with selenium ide by doing it :

```
storeTextPresent|myText|title
gotoIf|storedVars.tite|true
echo|${"true"}
```

but it doesnt work...i have : [error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://flowcontrol/content/extensions/goto-sel-ide.js?1347871647495, lineNumber -> 120.

Does anybody know how to get the return?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check for boolean support on gotoIf, but if gotoIf wants to go to a label, I don't see a label defined in the above script.
Also, the "storedVars.tite" reference looks to be misspelled.